# Looping in Angular with promises and http calls

Tags: arrays, angular, for-loop, promise, httprequest

my goal is to populate an array via for loop. and then send that array in `HTTP` `POST` call,

i.e: first upload all the files, then push each file details in array.

```
// For multiple files
for (let i = 0; i < projectRefFilesForUploading.length; i++) {
    this.postSingleFile([] = projectRefFilesForUploading[i].file, projectDir).then(uploadedFiles => {

        let filePath = uploadedFiles['projectRefFiles'][0].fd;
        filePath = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, filePath.lastIndexOf("."));
        let filename = uploadedFiles['projectRefFiles'][0].filename;
        let size = uploadedFiles['projectRefFiles'][0].size;
        let type = uploadedFiles['projectRefFiles'][0].type;
        let status = uploadedFiles['projectRefFiles'][0].status; // finished
        let fileNote = projectRefFilesForUploading[i].fileNote;

        projectRefFilesDataArray.push({fileName: filename, filePath: filePath, size: size, type: type, fileNote: fileNote});
    });   
}
```

i.e: now post the array in http post call.

```
let body = {
    projectId: projectId,
    projectRefFiles: projectRefFilesDataArray
}

let headers = new Headers();
let options: RequestOptionsArgs = { headers: headers, withCredentials: true }
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    this.http.post( this.apiEndpoint + "/add/all", body, options).toPromise()
    .then(response => {
        let jsonData = response.json();
        if (jsonData.apiStatus == 1) {
            resolve(jsonData);
        }
        else reject(jsonData.message);
    })
    .catch(reason => reject(reason.statusText));
});
```

the problem is due to `async` function calls, `http` call post its data in parallel to loop execution. so it sends an empty array in `http` call. if I put the call method inside the loop then it works. but it created too much `http` call along with looping.

please help me how to detect, loop finishes it execution then after `http` call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let count = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < projectRefFilesForUploading.length; i++) {
            this.postSingleFile([] = projectRefFilesForUploading[i].file, projectDir).then(uploadedFiles => {
                count++;
                let filePath = uploadedFiles['projectRefFiles'][0].fd;
                filePath = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, filePath.lastIndexOf("."));
                let filename = uploadedFiles['projectRefFiles'][0].filename;
                let size = uploadedFiles['projectRefFiles'][0].size;
                let type = uploadedFiles['projectRefFiles'][0].type;
                let status = uploadedFiles['projectRefFiles'][0].status; // finished
                let fileNote = projectRefFilesForUploading[i].fileNote;

                projectRefFilesDataArray.push({fileName: filename, filePath: filePath, size: size, type: type, fileNote: fileNote});
               if(count === projectRefFilesForUploading.length){
                  resolve(projectRefFilesForUploading);
               }
            });   
        }
        });


    promise.then(function(projectRefFilesDataArray){
    let body = {
        projectId: projectId,
        projectRefFiles: projectRefFilesDataArray
    }

    let headers = new Headers();
    let options: RequestOptionsArgs = { headers: headers, withCredentials: true }
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        this.http.post( this.apiEndpoint + "/add/all", body, options).toPromise()
        .then(response => {
            let jsonData = response.json();
            if (jsonData.apiStatus == 1) {
                resolve(jsonData);
            }
            else reject(jsonData.message);
        })
        .catch(reason => reject(reason.statusText));
    });

    });
```

Comment: in promise.then() method, inside promise of http post call, `response` and `reason` get undefined. any idea to fix it ?

Comment: your answer really helped, it needs little modification. anywaythanks

Comment: sorry i didnt' see your first reply. you are welcome.